# Excel Formula - How to extract date from a week with custom start date?

Tags: excel-formula

[Click for diagram explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXnDH.png)

Hi guys,
I have managed to find out formula for counting week 1 from custom start date and not from start of the year. (see first diagram above) I've achieved this by entering date manually and having a formula in week cell.

```
"**Week #"** =TRUNC(((A2-A1)+6)/7)+(WEEKDAY(A2)=WEEKDAY(A1))
```

Now I want to do it the other way round, rather than type in date every time, I want to type in a week number, relating week number from custom start date that would then be translated into proper date.

Comment: well one thing that has me confused is that 2016/08/22 - 2016/04/18 is 126 days appart, which is 18 weeks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

10 weeks later would simply be taking your start date adding 7 times the number of weeks or in this case 70 days.  Assuming your start date is in C2 and your number of weeks from C2 is in C4, then your formula would be as follows:

```
=(C2-1)+7*C4
```

As for your week number formula, you may want to consider changing it to:

```
=WEEKNUM(I3,2)-WEEKNUM(I2,2)+1
```

Where I2 is your start date and I3 is your second date.  The 2 in the weeknum formula is to tell it your week starts on a Monday.

Based on your comment about different years you could try:

```
=(WEEKNUM(I3,2)+52*(year(I3)-Year(I2)))-WEEKNUM(I2,2)+1
```

Comment: Excellent, it works :) Since I use Monday as week start I had to add "-7"  basically remove 7 days to reduce number of weeks given by formula and it is spot on. Week formula doesn't work as planned, let me see if I need it first at all.  Thank you

Comment: Week formula doesn't work as planned, all I get is a number and if cell format is set to date I get 9/01/1900. I used I2=18/04/16   and I3=20/06/16   I can still use previous cumbersome formula, yours looks like a very elegant solution though.

Comment: change your formatting on the cell with 9/01/1900 to general instead of date.  Also see update to formula for work weeks starting on Mondays.

Comment: You are brilliant :) thank you I still had 1 week too short for week formula but I added "+1" at end and it works as long as it is in the same year. My stages go from mid year to mid year next year and then I get negative number for weeks rather than continuing to count.

Comment: ahh then yes the week number would fall appart as it is basically the week number of the current year.  Let me add something that will check if it is in a future year.  See updated answer

Comment: Also note I put a -1 in the first formula.  the 2nd week is only 7 days after the 1st week, there for it is (2-1)*7 days after the start date.